# Add same item onto canvas multiple times

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

basically what I'm trying to do is create a 'raining effect' on the canvas (doesn't exactly look like rain at the moment but I will sort that later)

This is my JavaScript so far:

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback){
          window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function rectangle (x, y, w, h) {
    var randomx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width - 50);
    var randomy = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height - 100);
    this.x = randomx || x || 0;
    this.y = randomy || y || 0;
    this.w = w || 0;
    this.h = h || 0;

    this.draw = function () {
        cx.fillStyle = "blue";
        cx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    };
}

var myRectangle = new rectangle(window.randomx, window.randomy, 10, 10);

function loop () {
    cx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    myRectangle.y++;
    myRectangle.draw();
    requestAnimFrame(loop);
}

loop();
```

Basically, it will create a 10 by 10 blue block at a random y and x point of the canvas, what I need to do is keep adding this blue block over and over onto the canvas. I tried including this for loop into the 'loop' function:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var myRectangle = new rectangle(window.randomx, window.randomy, 10, 10);
}
```

But this just keeps flashing the block at random points (I understand why, it is because it keeps overwriting the variable and placing it at a new point), would anyone be able to help me? I know it would be easier to use jQuery for this, but I'm using JavaScript only

Here is a fiddle for what it looks like at the moment (without the for loop) thanks in advance!

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jqzx/)

Comment: make an array of rectangles. `myRectangle[i] = new rectangle(...)` instead.

Comment: @MarcB: I updated it to do just that. http://jsfiddle.net/8Jqzx/1/

Comment: Oh I see! @MarcB and CoreyOgburn Thank you both very much, if you turn your comment into an answer I'll accept it! Thanks again

Comment: When you change the rects into rain (into an image or more complex drawing) you might want to recycle the "drop" when it falls below the canvas.  When a drop falls below the canvas you could re-randomize its X and put its Y back above the canvas. Then let it fall again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an array of rectangles instead:

```
myRectangle[i] = new rectangle(...);
```

This way the previously generated ones won't get overwritten/destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using an array.  You also want to make sure you remove them when they're off the screen (note `expired` variable)

http://jsfiddle.net/8Jqzx/2/

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
      return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
              window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
              window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
              window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
              window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
              function(callback){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
              };
    })();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    cx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    function rectangle (x, y, w, h) {
        var randomx = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width - 50);
        var randomy = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height - 100);
        this.x = randomx || x || 0;
        this.y = randomy || y || 0;
        this.w = w || 0;
        this.h = h || 0;
        this.expired = false;

        this.draw = function () {
            cx.fillStyle = "blue";
            cx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        };
        this.update = function () {
            this.y++;
            if (y > canvas.height) {
                this.expired = true;
            }
        }
    }

    var rectangles = new Array();

    function newRect () {
        rectangles.push(new rectangle(window.randomx, window.randomy, 10, 10));
    }

    var timing = 0;

    function loop () {
        cx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        if (timing%10 == 0) {
            newRect();
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
            rectangles[i].update();
            rectangles[i].draw();
            if (rectangles[i].expired) {
                rectangles.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
        timing++;
        requestAnimFrame(loop);
    }

    loop();
```

But in this one you have them appear at the top (more rain-like): http://jsfiddle.net/8Jqzx/3/